# Using nested for loops to replace characters in an array of strings with the corresponding characters to the left or the right on a keyboard

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, replace

I am creating a program that will offer suggestions (like spell check) to a user entered text message using a read in file of 200,000+ words.

I need to create a method that will read in an Array of words (already sorted to be in postions 0-n based on length of the message) and then replace each character at position n with the corresponding character to the left or the right on a keyboard and store them into an ArrayList. This will then be passed to a method that will read the ArrayList, cross-reference it with the read-in dictionary, and return an ArrayList with the combinations that are actually words.

EX: Hello (position 0) there (position 1)
Alternate words: Hello, Jello, Gello, Hrllo, Hwllo, etc.

I am stuck trying to find a way to replace the characters at postion n with the ones to the left or the right on the keyboard. Any suggestions?

Here is the code so far:

```
public ArrayList <String> alternateWords (String [] w)
    {

        //declarations

        int p = 0; //position of characters inside array
        ArrayList<String> potentialWords = new ArrayList<String>(); //ArrayList to hold all potential words

        //Traverse array and replace letters in each word, then store in ArrayList

        for (int i = 0; i < w.length; i++) //loop for each word in a text message
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < w[p].length(); i++) //loop for each character in a text message
            {

                //REPLACE HAPPENS HERE
                p++; //increment position of character check
                //Store in arrayList

            } //End inner For

        } //End outer For

    } //End alternateWords
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this sort of data is static (for a given type of keyboard), it is best represented by an `enum`.

Here's a partial example:

```
public class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        char key = 'a';
        System.out.println(NextTo.valueOf(key).getLeft()+" is left of "+key);
        System.out.println(NextTo.valueOf(key).getRight()+" is right of "+key);
    }
}

enum NextTo {
    a(null, 's'),
    s('a', 'd'),
    d('s', 'f'),
    f('d', 'g');
    // ...

    private Character left;
    private Character right;

    public Character getLeft() {
        return left;
    }
    public Character getRight() {
        return right;
    }
    public static NextTo valueOf(char c) {
        return NextTo.valueOf(String.valueOf(c));
    }

    private NextTo(Character left, Character right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
}
```

which outputs

> null is left of a
>   s is right of a

I didn't add any sort of error-checking, or support for capital letters, but you get the idea.